# Is there a way to zero initialize a struct that is compatible between C and C++

Tags: c++, c, struct, initialization

**Problem:** I would like to write a code sample that is cross-compatible between C and C++.

I have a plain ol' data (POD) struct like this for example...

```
typedef struct blob {
    int size;
    uint8_t * data;
} blob;
```

Is there a simple way to zero initialize this that is valid in both C and C++?

If I understand correctly, the following initializers are not valid in both languages:

```
blob b = {0}; // valid C, invalid C++
blob b = {}; // valid C++, invalid C
```

The best I've found so far is:

```
blob b = {0,0};
```

... which is okay, but the real struct has 8 fields and that's getting into typo territory.

**Question:** Is there a common convention used, or a cross-compatible way of initialization that doesn't require knowledge of the fields?

Comment: memset? thats the old fashioned way

Comment: That's reasonable, but I was really hoping for a one-liner; something at time of definition.

Comment: `blob b = {0};` is valid C++. You might get a warning though.

Comment: It generates a warning, and so cannot be compiled with `-Werror` |

`warning: missing initializer for member ‘blob::data’ [-Wmissing-field-initializers]`

Comment: That's one of the few warnings I've been known to turn off. Sooner or later I'll come to regret it, but so far life has been good.

Comment: @user4581301 I'm with you on that one.  This gets my 'pointless warning of the year' award, especially if there's just a single, 0 initialiser.  The intent when you do that is obvious.

Comment: @pm100 Detail: `memset()` is not _initialization_, but assignment.

Comment: Can't we not teach C and C++ as the same base language anymore. There are enough subtle differences that we don't want people asking `C/C++` questions as the answer is always different for both languages. Teach C or teach C++.

Comment: @chux-ReinstateMonica Does `memset()` even count as assignment?  I'd say `memset()` is even further away from initialization than assignment is.

Comment: @AndrewHenle `memset(d, val, n)` is certainly at least _copying_ to what `d` points to.  The C spec does not use _assignment_ there.  In `scanf()` the data pointed to is _assigned_.  I do not see any fundamental difference between copy and assign here.  I _guess_ it is that `memset()` sets all the bits, even padding ones and potential trap values?  Perhaps a LL question.

Comment: Note that (in C++) neither of these zero-initialize the structure itself. Instead they zero-initialize the members. That means (in contrast to `memset`) padding might not be zeroed.

Answer (score 3):

OK, macros are the spawn of the devil, but would this be of any interest?

```
#ifdef __cplusplus
    #define ZERO_INIT
#else
    #define ZERO_INIT 0
#endif

...

blob b = {ZERO_INIT};
```

Or is such trickery a bit too naughty in tutorial code?

(Edited to reflect suggestions in the comments).

Comment: I do appreciate the answer, but yes, I believe a MACRO is perhaps too distracting in tutorial code.

Comment: Thought you might say that!

Comment: It is clever though!

Comment: I would change the macro so the line of code was: `blob b = {ZERO_INIT};`

Comment: @MartinYork Yes, perhaps that makes the code a little less obscure.

Comment: I'm ok with this answer. But I may suggest changing the macro to something less distracting like `zinit` (zero initialize) which is either `0` or an empty definition. Then code says `blob b = {zinit};`

Comment: @selbie Yes, that's what Martin suggested.  Answer edited, although I don't agree with your choice of name.  Macros in upper case, no?

Comment: @PaulSanders - good point.

Comment: If you insist on teaching a combined C/C++ tutorial, I'm not sure drawing attention to such distinctions is a bad thing.  That said, maybe avoid cleverness and put each declaration in a macro, rather than only the 0 itself.

Comment: @Brian I agree.  You don't even need a macro, just do `#ifdef __cplusplus  blob b = {}; #else blob b = { 0 }; #endif`.  And if you've got more than one thing to initialise, you can group them all together.

Answer (score 2):

This declaration

```
blob b = {0};
```

is valid in both C and C++.

If the C++ compiler supports the C++ 20 Standard then you can also write

```
blob b = { .size = 0, .data = 0 };
```

Comment: In C++ the intializer generates a warning, and so cannot be compiled with `-Werror`. | `warning: missing initializer for member ‘blob::data’ [-Wmissing-field-initializers]`

Comment: Also, I was hoping for a constructor that does _NOT_ require knowledge of the struct's fields.

Comment: @zak The warning settings you choose are not C++'s problem?

Comment: You're not wrong, but I think that is an over simplification. I have elected to enable all warnings, so my code won't be copied and generate warnings. Again, the goal is simplicity, and to make a good example for people to follow.